# hiding address bar from a pop-up window

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i am developing a website, as my website contain different products.. when a user click in any one the product from my list, the product details opens and is shown in another pop-up window.but that pop-up window opens with address bar that contains my product link.
Can anyone please help me to hide that pop-up window address bar and if possible status bar also from that pop-up window.

thanks in advance

my javascript:

```
window.open('sample.aspx?ProdName=" + productname +  "','','height=600,width=930,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,modal=yes')");
```

Comment: Check out the abundant documentation for the `window.open` method in javascript.

Comment: Try using a [JQuery modal window](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) instead of popup.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Modern browsers prevent popups from concealing the domain of the page they are showing by not providing a mechanism for hiding the address bar.

I'd recommend changing the design to avoid popups (which are a horrible piece of UX).

Answer (score 1):

You cant hide the address bar, but you can hide the status bar and toolbar and other things. [Here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml) is a good description of the parameters to the `window.open()` method.

```
window.open("http://www.my-domain.com", "My Title","status=0,toolbar=0");
```

In repsonse to comment:

```
window.open("sample.aspx?ProdName=" + productname, "height=600,width=930,status=0,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,scrollbars=1,modal=1");
```

Comment: i used window.open(); but still it is not hiding.

Comment: i added my script to my question.. please check it.

Comment: @arun Made changes in my answer

Comment: Chad i tried your script into my page, your code working fine in localhost. But when i upload my page to server it is not working.

Comment: Then you are running a popup blocker or something of the sort, there is nothing wrong with this code. Trying opening firebug's console, refreshing the page and see if you get any errors in your JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered showing an in-browser dialog, using JavaScript such as [jQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)?